# Day of publication of Church of England marriage banns in 1909

Tags: england, marriage-practices, anglican-church

The banns for the marriage of Albert Herbert William Proctor and Julia Ann Coulson were read on the 6th, 13th and 20th October 1908, which were 3 consecutive Tuesdays.  According to [Lord Hardwick's Act (Marriage Act 1753)](http://freepages.genealogy.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~framland/acts/1753.htm) banns were meant to be read on Sundays.  Were Sundays a strict requirement, or did the banns only need to be read during a service, which could happen on other days of the week?

Answer (score 7):

A rapid scan of *Marriage Law for Genealogists the definitive guide* by Rebecca Probert  (Probert, Rebecca *Marriage Law for Genealogists the definitive guide*. Kenilworth: Takeaway (Publishing), 2009.) suggests that although Banns were supposed to be read on Sundays, the marriage would still be valid -- i.e. 'Sunday Banns' are a directory requirement, not a mandatory one. Failure to comply with a mandatory requirement renders the marriage void, whereas directory requirements are desirable but not fundamental.

I thoroughly recommend the Probert book for the nitty-gritty of English and Welsh marriage laws and reality from 1600 on.